# Django Framework: Object does not display on web page for specific pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to import specific items from a database into a web page using Django Framework. I have managed to do this when I pull **all** the records but not when I try to pick individual records by their primary key.

Here is the html to display the page and database fields:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <br>
    <h3>Adherence agreement for authorized access to data and biospecimens in the RD-Connect Genome-Phenome Analysis Platform (RDC-GPAP)<sup><a href="#fn1" id="ref1">1</a></sup><small class="text-muted"> to be used together with the <span class="text-info">Code of Conduct</span> for integrated user access to RDC-GPAP for health-related information and human biological samples.</small></h3>
    <hr>

    {% for item in items %}

    <p>I, <span class="text-success">{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</span>, acting on behalf of the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span>, and holding the position <span class="text-success">{{ item.job_title }}</span>, herewith declare:</p>
    <ol type="1">
        <li>I have the authority to represent and engage the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> for the purpose of the project, <span class="text-success">[project name]</span>. For this project we ask for access to data and/or biospecimens in accordance with our research interests as set out in our completed <span class="text-info">User Verification Form</span> (previous page).</li>
        <br>
        <li>The <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> agrees to fully endorse and adhere to the <span class="text-info">Code of Conduct</span> for integrated user access to the RDC-GPAP for health-related information and human biological samples, version 2, 3rd November 2017. It shall apply to all data and biospecimen processing activities carried out within the project <span class="text-success">[project name]</span>. The personal data protection framework is thus in part formalized through this Code.</li>
        <br>
        <li>The <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> will ensure the implementation of all measures required by the provisions of this Code.</li>
        <br>
        <li>The <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> will ensure compliance with this Code by all staff and personnel working within the project on behalf of the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span>.</li>
        <br>
        <li>In addition to the rules laid out by the Code, the following project specific rules shall apply:</li>
        <br>
        <ol type="a">
            <li>There will be no attempt to try to identify or contact data or donor subjects.</li>
            <li>Accessed data and biospecimens will not be redistributed.</li>
            <li>Access codes and user logins are specific to the identified user and are strictly non-transferable.</li>
            <li>Accessed datasets will be destroyed once they are no longer used.</li>
            <li>Biospecimens will be handled in accordance with specifications in a Material Transfer Agreement.</li>
            <li>Publications using any form of data accessed through the RDC-GPAP will contain an acknowledgment and a reference of the RDC-GPAP as appropriate.
            Where a publication makes use of individual-level datasets and enriched phenotypic data, authors should consider whether the intellectual contribution of the original contributors of the datasets qualifies for authorship positions in line with standard publication practice.</li>
            <li>Results of analyses of accessed data and biospecimens will be returned to the platform. Published work will also be sent to RD-Connect.</li>
            <li>In case of misconduct access to the platform will be withdrawn.</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
    <hr>
    <p>Signed on behalf of the <span class="text-success">{{ item.department }}</span> on <span class="text-success">{% now "jS F Y" %}</span> by <span class="text-success">{{ item.first_name }} {{ item.last_name }}</span>:</p>

    {% endfor %}

    <br>
    <br>
    <p>…………………………………………………</p>
    <p>Signature</p>
    <hr>
    <sup id="fn1">1. This adherence agreement is based on the Personal Data Directive, Directive95/46/EC, implying that all personal data shall be handled in accordance with Secrecy law.<a href="#ref1" title="Jump back to footnote 1 in the text.">↩</a></sup>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="printDiv('printable')" value="Print" />
    <br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py:`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('adherence_agreement/', views.adherence_agreement, name='adherence_agreement'),
]
```

Then when I use the following code in `views.py`, I get the relevant fields in the web page by iterating `data` with `{% for item in items %}` and choosing individual fields with e.g. `{{ item.first_name }}`:

```
def adherence_agreement(request):
    try:
        data = UserInfo.objects.all()
    except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('User does not exist')
    return render(
        request,
        'adherence_agreement.html', {
            'items': data
        }
    )
```

However, if I want to pull in information for a specific record by changing the `urlpattern` to `path('adherence_agreement/<int:id>'...` and changing `views.py` like so:

```
def adherence_agreement(request,id):
    try:
        data = UserInfo.objects.get(pk=id)
    except UserInfo.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('User does not exist')
    datum = data._meta.get_fields()
    return render(
        request,
        'adherence_agreement.html', {
            'items': datum
        }
    )
```

Then the web page loads up (no errors) but none of the fields are pulled through...

FYI, the `models.py` for `UserInfo`:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    first_name              = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='First Name', help_text='Your given name. *REQUIRED**')
    last_name               = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name', help_text='Your family name. *REQUIRED*.')
    office_address          = models.CharField(max_length=200 ,verbose_name='Office address', help_text='The address where you can be reached rather than your institution’s head office. *REQUIRED*')
    research_interest       = models.CharField(max_length=1000 ,verbose_name='Short summary of your research interests',help_text='In one or two sentences please describe your research interests and how access to the RD-Connect platform is relevant for you. *REQUIRED*' )
    institution             = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name of institution', help_text='The institution (university, hospital etc.) with which you have your primary affiliation. *REQUIRED*')
    institute_website       = models.URLField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default="", verbose_name='Institute website', help_text='Your institution’s main website.')
    job_title               = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Position within institution', help_text='Your job title within your institution.')
    email                   = models.EmailField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Institutional email address', help_text='Use of an institutional email address issued by your place of work is part of our validation procedure. If you do not have one please contact help@rd-connect.eu to explain your circumstances')
    department              = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Name of your department', help_text='Your department within your institution (e.g. Neurology, Genetics, etc.')
    orcid_profile           = models.URLField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ORCID profile', help_text='If you have an ORCID profile, please paste the link here.')
    linkedin_profile        = models.URLField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='LinkedIn profile', help_text='If you have a LinkedIn profile, please paste the link here.')
    publications            = models.URLField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Three recent publications', help_text='Please paste links to three recent representative publications of which you are an author (link to the article on the journal website or to the PubMed page).')
    researchgate_profile    = models.URLField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='ResearchGate profile', help_text='If you have a ResearchGate profile, please paste the link here.')
    departmentweb_profile   = models.URLField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Department web profile', help_text='If you or your group has a profile on your university or departmental website please paste the link here.')
    adherence_agreement     = models.FileField(verbose_name='Adherence Agreement', help_text='I confirm that I have read the Code of Conduct and signed the Adherence Agreement and agree to abide by the rules therein. In confirmation of this I upload a signed copy of the Adherence Agreement here.')
    photo_scan              = models.FileField(verbose_name='Photo ID scan', help_text = 'As part of our verification procedure we require a recognised form of ID such as your passport, national ID card or driving licence. Please scan, save and upload here as a JPEG or PDF.')
    confirm_listing         = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='I agree that my name can be listed as a user of the platform on the RD-Connect official website (https://rd-connect.eu)', help_text='All users will be stored in internal RD-Connect records for internal purposes and may be presented in reports to the European Commission as our funding organisation. We would also like to list users in a dedicated section of the platform website. If you do not wish your name to be listed publicly, do not tick the box.')
    newsletter_subscribed   = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='I would like to be subscribed to the RD-Connect Newsletter', help_text='We would like to register all users for our monthly newsletter in order to keep you updated about news of interest to rare disease researchers and platform updates. If you do not wish to receive the newsletter, please tick the box.')
    created                 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date                    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date')

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the Model object
        """
        return self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Returns the url to access a detail record for this user
        """
        return reverse('user-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you're doing `datum = data._meta.get_fields()` in the view. That gets the class-level field objects, which you don't want at all. Don't do that; pass the object directly to the template.

You will also need to remove the loop in the template and pass the object directly as `item`.

As a further optimisation, you can use `get_object_or_404` rather than catching the DoesNotExist exception and raising a 404 manually.

```
def adherence_agreement(request,id):
    item = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, pk=id)
    return render(request, 'adherence_agreement.html', {'item': item})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your template is expecting an iterable and you're retrieving a single item so you can place it in a list to make it iterable.  You can also cut down on code by using `get_object_or_404` (which throws a 404 if not found).

```
def adherence_agreement(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, pk=id)
    return render(
        request,
        'adherence_agreement.html', 
        {
            'items': [data]
        }
    )
```